# APIs not getting deployed in one gateway in latest API Manager(wso2am-4.0.0)

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I'm using the latest API Manager(wso2am-4.0.0) and I am trying to implement one control plane node(which also acts as a separate gateway node), and also a gateway worker node as per the documentation.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/deploy-api/deploy-through-multiple-api-gateways/

Currently, the APIs are getting deployed to the gateway worker node as expected(when accessing via port 8243) but not getting deployed to the control plane node, which results in a 404 not found when invoking the API via the control plane node(when accessing via port 8244).

The relevant deployment.conf configurations for both the nodes are as below.

**Control Plane**

```
[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Production Gateway"
type = "production"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "Production Gateway Environment"
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://localhost:9443/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://localhost:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://localhost:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://localhost:8280"
https_endpoint = "https://localhost:8243"

[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Default"
type = "hybrid"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "External Gateway Environment"
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://localhost:9444/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://localhost:9100"
wss_endpoint = "wss://localhost:8100"
http_endpoint = "http://localhost:8281"
https_endpoint = "https://localhost:8244"
```

**Gateway Worker**

```
[apim.key_manager]
service_url = "https://<hostname>:9443/services/"
username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"

[apim.throttling]
service_url = "https://<hostname>:9443/services/"
throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://<hostname>:5672"]

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://<hostname>:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://<hostname>:9711"]

[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway]
gateway_labels =["Default","Production Gateway"]
```

Note: I started these servers using the switches -Dprofile=control-plane and -Dprofile=gateway-worker respectively.

Am I missing any configuration here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: CP cannot act as a gateway. You have to use either another gateway instance or an all-in-one instance.

Comment: @RrR Thanks for the reply. Can you kindly elaborate on what is meant by all-in-one instance?

Comment: All-in-one instance means, running the API Manager without any profiles (starting the server without specifying any profiles such as `control-plane` or `gateway-worker`). Note that once the server is started with a profile, it has to always get started with the same profile (otherwise, you may encounter issues when starting with different profiles). In your case, you can start a new API Manager server in your environment after configuring the pack as required.

Comment: @Athiththan Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to configure one server as an all-in-one instance and another as a separate gateway-worker instance? The requirement is to be able to deploy an API to one or both of the instances as required.

Comment: Yes, you can configure one server as an All-in-one instance and another as a Gateway instance to achieve your requirement.